# Parentheses Balancing in scala

Tags: scala

I got a assignment for balancing parentheses using scala. I wrote this code:

```
def balance(chars: List[Char]): Boolean = {

def check(sent: List[Char], count: Int): Int =
  if (sent.isEmpty)
    count
  else if (sent.head == '(')
    check(sent.tail, count + 1)
  else if (sent.head == ')')
    check(sent.tail, count - 1)
  else
    check(sent.tail, count)

     check(chars, 0) == 0 }
```

but this code fails in `"())("` 
any idea to implement this code correct?

Comment: You're going to break honor code.

Comment: https://www.coursera.org/about/honorcode

Comment: If you have zero open parentheses, and you find a close parentheses, is everything cool, or is something wrong?  Now, can you make your code reflect this?

Comment: You should try to think of the parentheses as having a canceling effect. When you see a left paren, save it. When you see a right paren, remove the left paren. The idea is that at the end of the process, whatever container you were putting parentheses in is empty.

Comment: Also, don't try to pawn your coursera hw on others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not giving any code away, just clarifying the likely spec.  All your code is doing is counting the number of right and left parens, and making sure they are equal.  That's a necessary condition, but not sufficient.   For balanced parentheses, you also need to show that as you scan through the string, the number of '('s you have seen must always be greater than or equal to the number of ')'s seen.